# Calculate in Excel Sum of Days given 2 date ranges (Start date , End date), aggregate monthly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please find the excel data.

Input format:

```
ID  Begin Date  End Date    Comment
1   07/25/17    08/16/17    July 6 days, August 16 days
2   05/01/17    05/11/17    11 Days in May
3   07/10/17    07/16/17    6 days in July
```

Output format:

```
Jan-17  Feb-17  Mar-17  Apr-17  May-17  Jun-17  Jul-17  Aug-17..... Dec
                                  11              12       16
```

How to get this aggregate at month level, given a range

Input Format:

[image]

Output format:

[image]

Comment: an xl worksheet isn't a twitter post.

Comment: Your example results are inconsistent. Do you want to include the start date or don't you? For example you say 5/1/17 to 5/11/17 is 11 days in May (indicating that you *do* want to include the start date), but that 7/10/17 to 7/16/17 is 6 days in July (indicating that you *don't* want to include the start date). Which is it? Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you including start date and end date because your results aren't consistent. If **ID2** is 11 days then shouldn't **ID3** be 7?

Assuming that you want to include both start date and end date then you can do that like this:

Put the **first** of each month in `A8` copied across (formatted as mmm-yy) then use this array formula in `A9`

`=SUM(TEXT(IF($B2:$B4="",0,IF($C2:$C4>EOMONTH(A8,0),EOMONTH(A8,0),$C2:$C4)-IF($B2:$B4<A8,A8,$B2:$B4)+1),"0;\0")+0)`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy across

This only counts rows that have both start and end date

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes if there is Begin date and end Date is not available and vice versa. Can you give the formula for aggregating only if both (Begin and End) are present i.e., skip aggregating if anyone is NULL

Comment: @SudhamshKandukuri I edited the formula above so that it only considers rows that have both start and end date